# Как избавится от switch case в Asp.Net Core MVC коде?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc

Всем привет!
Делаю калькулятор на Asp.Net Core MVC и у меня получился очень большой Switch Case.
Помогите пожалуйста переделать мой код.

Вот мой контроллер:

```
 public class CalcController : Controller
    {
        public IActionResult IndexCalculator()
        {
            return View(new CalcModel());
        }


        [HttpPost]
        public async Task<IActionResult> IndexCalculator(CalcModel model)
        {

            ModelState.Clear();
          
            switch (model.calculationMethod)
            {
                case CalculationMethod.Addition:
                    model.Result = model.FirstNumber + model.SecondNumber;
                    break;
                case CalculationMethod.Subtraction:
                    model.Result = model.FirstNumber - model.SecondNumber;
                    break;
                case CalculationMethod.Multiplication:
                    model.Result = model.FirstNumber * model.SecondNumber;
                    break;
                case CalculationMethod.Division:
                    if (model.SecondNumber == 0)
                        break;
                    else
                        model.Result = model.FirstNumber / model.SecondNumber;
                    break;
                case CalculationMethod.X2:
                    model.Result = Math.Pow(model.FirstNumber, 2);
                    break;
                case CalculationMethod.Sqrt:
                    model.Result = Math.Sqrt(model.FirstNumber);
                    break;
                case CalculationMethod.Sinsus:
                    model.Result = Math.Sin((model.FirstNumber * Math.PI) / 180);
                    break;
                case CalculationMethod.Cosinus:
                    model.Result = Math.Cos((model.FirstNumber * Math.PI) / 180);
                    break;
                case CalculationMethod.Tangens:
                    model.Result = Math.Tan((model.FirstNumber * Math.PI) / 180);
                    break;
                case CalculationMethod.Cotangens:
                    model.Result = Math.Sqrt((Math.Cos((model.FirstNumber * Math.PI) / 180)) / (Math.Sin((model.FirstNumber * Math.PI) / 180)));
                    break;
            }

            return View(model);

        }
        
    }
}
```

Так же вот моя модель:

```
namespace MyWeb.Models
{
    public  class CalcModel
    {

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Поле должно быть установлено")]
        public double FirstNumber { get; set; }
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Поле должно быть установлено")]
        public double SecondNumber { get; set; }
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Поле должно быть установлено")]
        public double Result { get; set; }
        public CalculationMethod calculationMethod { get; set; }
        

        public enum CalculationMethod
        {
            
            Addition = '+',
            Subtraction = '-',
            Multiplication = '*',
            Division = '/',
            X2 = 'x',
            Sqrt = '√',
            Sinsus = 'S',
            Cosinus = 'C',
            Tangens = 'T',
            Cotangens = 'K'
        }
        
    }
}
```

Как сделать мой код лучше?

Comment: Да в целом никак не избавиться. Можно накрутить синтаксического сахара, выделить свич в отдельный метод, будет код прикольнее смотреться, но логику улучшить не получится.

Comment: Да не такой уж и большой. Вполне аккуратно и понятно все. Код в первую очередь должен быть не компактный, а понятный.

Comment: switch всегда можно поменять на словарь

Comment: Но в вашем случае я бы все вычисления еще и в отдельный класс выделил

Comment: @tym32167 есть шальная мысль напилить методов, и с фронта сразу вызывать нужный. Тогда switch полностью уедет на фронт (но он наверное там и так есть). Перечисление на бэке можно выкинуть будет. Кстати модели запроса и ответа стоило бы разделить. Просто я в аспнетах не шарю, поэтому ответа не дам.

Comment: @aepot это ж калькулятор, можно хоть весь код на фронт вынести, бекенд не нужен для того, чтобы сложение посчитать.

Answer (score 1):

Любое изменение в данном коде приводит к усложнению. Поэтому если "очень большой switch" это единственная проблема, то ничего менять не нужно.

Можно ещё придраться к тому, что добавление новых операций требует изменения метода `IndexCalculator`. В некоторых случаях это проблема, в других нет.

Чтобы сделать метод `IndexCalculator' закрытым для изменений, примените паттерн [команда](https://refactoring.guru/ru/design-patterns/command). То есть вынесите расчет результата каждой операции в отдельный класс: AddCommand, SubtractCommand, MultiplyCommand, и т.д.

Затем объявите глобальную (статическую) переменную типа Dictionary<string, ICalculationCommand>, и заполните его во время загрузки приложения. В Asp.Net Core приложении для этого подойдёт метод Startup.Configure.

Теперь метод IndexCalculator можно упростить до:

```cs
[HttpPost]
public async Task<IActionResult> IndexCalculator(CalcModel model)
{

    ModelState.Clear();
     
    ICalculationCommand command;
    if(!AllCalculationCommands.TryGetValue(model.calculationMethod, out command) {
        return BadRequest();
    }
     model.result = command.Calculate(model.firstNumber, model.secondNumber);
     return View(model);
}
```

Как видите, у этого подхода есть недостаток - каждая операция требует отдельного класса. Это может быть оправдано лишь если вы делаете расширяемый библиотечный модуль. А для реализации данной функции в контроллере вполне годится один большой switch.

Comment: `глобальную (статическую) переменную` вот до этого момента было хорошо :)